# With LoaderMax: How to show a "content is loading" image/swf, while it is loading the original file?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, loading

working with LoaderMax is really great, and it works pretty well.

Now my question is: As there exists the alternateUrl property, is there a property, or at least an easy way for something like an "onLoadUrl".

Basically, I want to show a small, local stored swf or jpg (text: "is loading...") while the original image gets loaded from a webserver. As the main load() is complete, the loading img can be disposed?

Any idea for a best practice?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just show the "load"-image right away and use the `onComplete`-handler to swap the "load" image with the loaded image:

```
var img:Sprite = new Sprite();
// add "load" image ...
addChild(img);

// create loader
var img2:Sprite = new Sprite();
var loader:ImageLoader = new ImageLoader("image1.jpg", {onComplete:imageLoaded, container:img2});

// start loading
loader.load();

// event handler
function imageLoaded(event:LoaderEvent):void 
{
    // remove "load" image ...
    removeChild(img);

    // add loaded image
    addChild(img2);
}
```

Comment: thanks, i also thought something on this way. Or going with onProgress.

Comment: `onProgress` is mainly for status updates, i.e. when you want to show a progressbar ... or you could use the `onProgress` to avoid showing the "loading" image when the other image is already cached -> only show the "loading" image when the `onProgress` is at least called 5 times or something ...